# How to echo output of a top into a text file?

Tags: command-line, output, top

I want to write batch or something, that will write output of `top` into a file on login.

I did `top >> output-file`, but it contains some strange character!

Can somebody give a simple tutorial about how to write batch file in Linux?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try the following

```
top -b -n1 > filename.txt
```

The `-b` is for batch mode, which should prevent the strange characters. The `-n1` tells it to only print one iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Go to terminal and type:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ top > filename.txt
```

The output of top command will be now stored in a text file which is located in your Home directory.

See: [Bash scripting Tutorial](http://www.linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial).

Comment: As I said I did it but it store some binary character within it.